# Differentiate and integrate as mathematical terms

Tags: terminologie, mathématiques

I would like to know what the French verb is for 'to differentiate' and 'to integrate', as in

> “I am differentiating the curve y = x^2”

and

> “I am integrating the line y = 3x”.

I checked Collins English-French Dictionary and it wasn't so helpful.

1. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/differentiate
2. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/integrate

Answer (score 2):

The verb "dériver" has two important meanings in mathematics:

1. to obtain the derivative of a function; it's the translation of "to differentiate" in the present case.

   ex: Si on dérive f(x)=x² on obtient f'(x)=2x.
2. to deduce a mathemetical fact through the use of logical principles and principles of the theory at hand; in other words to prove a theorem or a lemma; it's then the translation of "to deduce" or "to derive".

ex: On dérive ce théorème à partir des théorèmes 3, 4, et 5 de la section précédente.

3. For the verb "to integrate" there is no other word in French than "intégrer".

ex: Si on intègre la fonction exponentielle on obtient encore la fonction exponentielle.

Answer (score 1):

You will translate as in the following:

> to differentiate = dériver
>
> to integrate = intégrer

edit: if I look for the meaning of `differentiate`, the definition match with french `dériver` (If I `dérive` f(x) = x^2 I got f'(x)=2x). but if I look for the translation of `dériver` in maths meaning I got `to derive`.

Are `to differentiate` and `to derive`synonyms?

Comment: The correct verb in English is to differentiate. Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863148/derive-or-differentiate